# html code can't preview in Chrome via Sublime text 2 (have already build system)

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext2

Html code can't preview in Chrome.

I wrote html code in **sublime text 2**.(learning web-development from Udacity)
I have already built the system in sublime:

```
C:\\Users\\$User$\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe.
```

but when the file is opened by chrome, it just showed the text I wrote in plain text, not in Html format.

Can anyone help? 
thanks

(I'm using windows 7)

Comment: look here http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=38831

Comment: thx varun, but it' doesn't work

Comment: I checked the link  sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=38831.There's no problem to open in chrome but show html format in chrome.I have already built the path like the link did.But it just showed text in opening page like this: <form><input></form>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using chrome refresh add on.

```
 https://github.com/teddyknox/SublimeChromeRefresh
```

Comment: press ctrl+shift+p in chrome or sublime text 2? either way can't show the command line to type Chrome Refresh: Enable/Disable